# Save a project as new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, save

Im new in android programming and wounder, how do make a copy of your android project in Android Studio?

I would like to save my project as a new version of my project for backup purpose. I tried just make a copy of the project in the finder and open the copied projectversion in Android Studio but it just seem to point to my old projectversion, not the new one.

How do I manage this simple and basic task?

Comment: "for backup purpose" I'm not saying you might have a need for this, but backup is a poor requirement. To achieve backup you should learn to use a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) such as [GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just want to save my project as new versions for trying different things out. Is Git the way to go? Of course I know Github but Im not sure how it is connected to android studio? So I guess my question is: **How do I save different versions of my project in android studio?**  I noticed that theres also in the VCS-meny something called "Local History". Is that automatically backing up my project with the possibility of reverting to older version?
What if I just want to save it as another project?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is down to the workspace files in the `.idea` folder keeping absolute paths as I noticed this phenomenon when attempting to move a project.

## Solution

When you have copied (or moved) the project, do not open with "Open an existing Android Studio Project", but instead open with "Import Non-Android Studio project" and select the main `build.gradle` file. This will fix the paths in the workspace.

[image: Open project dialog]